# Ending a NodeJS console program

Tags: node.js, zombie.js

Just have a newbie question with NodeJS.  I'm using the Zombie library to create a simple console program to scrape a page.

When I run the below code, I get the log statements in the order that I expect them (i.e. Done, then Navigated).

```
var Browser = require("zombie");

Browser.visit("https://www.apple.com",function(){
    console.log("Navigated");
});


console.log("Done!");
```

However, the console program doesn't seem to end.  I have to do a Ctrl-C to stop the execution of the program for some reason.  If I comment everything except for the last log statement ("Done!"), the program exits after it prints the log.

Why is this?

Comment: What if you try "http" instead of "httpS"?

Answer (score 0):

Try using another site instead of www.apple.com.

Ie. if you try www.google.com, www.stackoverflow.com or similar, it works. The Zombie browser will try to execute all the Javascript on the page before executing the callback function, and it is possible that apple.com JS is doing something funky confusing Zombie (and phantom.js under the hub there.)